# React hooks useState with Array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

How to push new element inside useState array React hook?
My code doesn't work!!
Only Last doc.data() is remained

```
const [friends, setFriends] = useState([]);

db.collection('users').doc(user.email).collection('friends').onSnapshot(snapshot => (  
    snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        setFriends(...friends, doc.data());
    })
))
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what's your expectation, and do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

This way you are sure you are doing it right

```
setFriends(prevFriends => [...prevFriends, doc.data()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put brackets around the values inside of your `setFriends` call.  This makes it an array.

```
setFriends([...friends, doc.data()]);
```